# Custom taxonomy if statement

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have a custom taxonomy `job-time` with categories such as `part-time` and `full-time`, what I'm trying to do is a simple IF statement where if the Job Time is Part Time it displays a message and IF it's Full Time, it displays something else.

I've been looking into this and found this code;

```
<?php if ( is_tax( 'job-time', 'part-time' ) ) {?>
    Yes
<?php } elseif ( is_tax( 'job-time','full-time' ) ) {?>
    No
<?php } ?>
```

However nothing outputs and not sure why?

Can anyone help please?

Comment: What's the context? If the `job-time` of the current post is `full-time`/`part-time`? Or if the job sector that you're browsing is `full-time`/`part-time`? Like, is this going on an archive page, or a single page?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want to display that information on a single post or a post type?

`is_tax()` conditional tag is used to determine if the **archive** page of a particular taxonomy/term is displayed. ([documented in codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax))

What you're probably looking for is `has_term()` function ([documented in codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/)).

So in your case the full condition would be:

```
<?php if ( has_term( 'part-time', 'job-time' ) ) { ?>
    Yes
<?php } elseif ( has_term( 'full-time', 'job-time' ) ) { ?>
    No
<?php } ?>
```

*NOTE: That works withing the default loop (checks the current post), if you want to check term of some other post, you could pass a post ID as a third parameter.*